# After racking my cider has turned a very dark color. What may be the problem or is there one?

Tags: cider, problems

I have two batches of pear cider, one I used an American yeast and one I used a champagne yeast. 
After racking the the airlocks were replaces and I have about 4 gallons in a 6.5 gallon glass carboy. A week after racking the champagne yeast batch has turned a darker brown then that of the American yeast batch. Is there something wrong and if so what could i do to fix it?

Comment: have you tasted them?

Answer (score 2):

Probably nothing to worry about. As the yeast drops out of suspension, the perceived colour becomes darker, as less light is reflected by the yeast. The yeast in the darker batch is likely dropping faster than the lighter batch. Give them a few weeks and the colours should be the same.

Comment: This was exactly going to be my answer.  Its what I have seen time and time again with beer and cider as well.  If you ever do a side by side comparison of WLP001 and WLP002 with the same wort in the same type carboy you'll never doubt the color perception again.

Answer (score 1):

It could be oxidation causing the color change. This can happen if the cider is sloshed/splashed during transfers after fermentation is complete.